# Adding Click Event to a Button in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to add click event to a button element which I added it dynamically within the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event function by running executeScript function.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "execute.js" });
})
```

I add a click event function to the dynamically added button element with this code inside executed execute.js file but it didn't work;

```
var btnComment=document.createElement('button');
btnComment.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log('btnComment worked')
});
```

I use background.html page inside it request to background.js file. How can I implement this function?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately due to a lack of context in terms of what your program looks like I can't give a 100% sure answer.  However, I believe the problem is that you need to specifically select the element first using the DOM.

try

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log('btnComment worked')
});
```

more info about the Document Object Model can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

**EDIT: spelling**

Answer (score 1):

Does your backround.html have this?

`<script src="background.js"></script>`

Note that you create your button in execute.js, but your html uses background.js so in your **background.js** file, you will need this:

```
function onButtonClicked (){
  console.log('btnComment worked');
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', onButtonClicked());
```

btw, I'm also still learning google chrome extensions.

Comment: I think it should be `addEventListener('click', onButtonClicked);` otherwise, the action function will be called.